# Windows 7 Stuck Loading Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-7, boot

I removed McAfee, rebooted, and let windows install some updates. Then when trying to boot again, I get stuck just before the welcome screen loads. It has the blue background you see on the welcome screen, but no text or list of user accounts. Only the background, and the cursor.

I have tried booting in Safe-Mode, but it seems to ignore F8. I know it's not not me as I've booted into Safe Mode hundreds of times, and I know it's not a broken key because after pressing it a few times, you will hear a system beep every time you press the key.

I have also tried letting it do Startup Repair, but when trying to load the Startup repair, I experience the same problem.

Any ideas?

Windows 7 Home Premium
Dell Inspiron N5030

[image: Picture of the screen]

Comment: Have you tried hitting CTRL+SHIFT+ESC here?  That will HOPEFULLY give you the Task Manager and maybe you can see a process that is responsible for this that you can kill?  Aside from that... when you say the "Startup Repair", are you booting off of the Windows 7 DVD and using THAT startup repair and it's doing this still?

Comment: Another thought... how long have you left it here?  Windows Updates can sometimes take awfully long times (sometimes stupid long times) to properly apply and many times they can do this without much explanation or outward sign.  Is your drive light hitting?  If so, is it hitting in sort of a regular pattern or is it more randomish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure there are no bootable CD/DVD or flash-drives plugged into the PC**

I had forgotten that earlier I had tried to burn the recovery CD/DVDs, and it had failed. I had forgot to take out the DVD and it turns out the DVD being in the drive is the reason it would not load. I'm posting this answer in case anyone else experiences this issue.

Comment: You're right. The screen capture looks like the background for Windows 7 screen.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 stuck at the welcome screen solved

1. Download Windows to flash software.
2. Put the Windows 7 installation disc into DVD drive and use `wintoflash` software to create a bootable USB drive (it takes only 5 min).
3. WinToFlash starts a wizard that will help pull over the contents of a Windows installation CD or DVD and prep the USB drive to become a bootable replacement for the optical drive..
4. Every time you start the computer plug in this pen drive which we created and there will not be any starting problems.